# DhtmlxScheduler with timeline view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dhtmlx

i have injected the Schedulerplugin into the view using [this tutorial](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/creating-event-calendar-with-dhtmlxscheduler-and-angularjs/)
I have also included the necessary files.

the plugin is working and i have the scheduler in my view. The problem is that i cant figure out how to add the timeline view. I have the license for it and all.

I have tried [this tutorial](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html) but I can't seem to get anyway with it. I've put the scheduler.createTimelineView into the directive from first link. But i get error "scheduler.createTimelineView is no a function".

I have also tried [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910472/add-timeline-event-on-dhtmlx-scheduler-in-angularjs) but no luck.
Anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 1):

> But i get error "scheduler.createTimelineView is no a function".

Usually, this indicates that timeline extension hasn't been added to the page. Make sure to add **ext/dhtmlxscheduler_timeline.js** to the page right after **dhtmlxscheduler.js**, i.e.

```
<script src="lib/scheduler/dhtmlxscheduler.js"></script>
<script src="lib/scheduler/ext/dhtmlxscheduler_timeline.js"></script>
```

Comment: Allright. So that works now, but i'm not able to initially add events now - they simply won't render. Only able to create them in the app.

Comment: It can be caused by the format of start_date/end_date dates in your data feed - it must match format set in `scheduler.config.xml_date`.
You can check the state of the scheduler after you load data to see if that's the case. Execute either `scheduler.getEvents()` or `scheduler._events` in browser console - if you'll get some events and they'll have obviously incorrect dates (1970s or so) - you can be sure that's it.
And a fix - change either xml_date or a format of dates in your data feed.
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_xml_date_config.html